# Symfony2 - Generate a PDF with HTML2PDF

Tags: php, symfony, html2pdf

I'm a new user in Symfony2, I would like to generate a PDF and I don't succeess to create a correct PDF with [HTML2PDF](http://html2pdf.fr/en/default). In fact, I have a pdf with 1 page containing a junk string like this : "HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Mon, 11 Mar 2013 19:37:29 GMT" and I have some additional line-break...

I would like to know if my method to generate a pdf is correct, that is return a php template who generate the pdf using HTML2PDF.

Here my controller code :

```
public function exec_cuAction($id)
{
//CU 4 : imprimer toutes les factures
switch ($id){
    case 2: 
        $infos = null;
        $html= $this->render('PeriscopeAdminBundle:Admin:FactureVide.html.twig',array('infos'=> $infos)); //les content pour le pdf
        $name = 'factureVide.pdf';                      
        return $this->render('PeriscopeAdminBundle:Admin:afficher_factures_pdf.html.php', array('name'=>$name, 'html'=>$html));
        break;
}
```

Here my PDF content :

```
<page orientation="portrait" format="A4" style="font-size: 18px">
   <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="left_informations">


                <br><br><br>

                <div id="fields">
                    <div id="invoice_id">
                        <span>Facture n____ </span>
                        <span>____________</span>
                        <span>Date : ___/___/______</span>
                    </div><br>
                    <div>Nom de l'enfant :</div><br>
                    <div>Primaire/Maternelle : </div><br>
                    <div>Date de naissance : </div><br>
                    <div>Classe : </div><br>
                    <div>Enseignant : </div><br>
                    <div>Taux horaire :</div><br>
                    <div>Heures matin : </div><br>
                    <div>Heures soir : </div><br>
                    <div>Total heures : </div>
                    <h4>Net  payer du mois : </h4>
                    <br>
                    <div>Votre retard  la fin du mois precédent : </div><br>
                    <h4>RETARD : </h4>
                    <div>Votre situation nette : </div>
                    <br>
                    <div> Association loi 1901, SIRET 39217524600017    Code APE 913 E <br>
                          Exonr de TVA Article 261 du CGI
                    </div>
                    <div><i>Partie  conserver</i></div>
                    <div style="width:610px;">---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</div>
                    <br>
                    <div id="invoice_id">
                        <span>Facture n____ </span>
                        <span>____________</span>
                        <span>Date: __/__/_____</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>Nom de l'enfant :</div>
                    <br>
                    <div>Votre situation nette : </div>
                    <br>
                    <div>Payer en espce la somme de :</div>
                    <br>
                    <div>Payer par chque  l'ordre de Priscope n</div>
                    <div style="margin-left:100px;">Banque : </div>
                    <div style="margin-left:100px;">Somme : </div>
                    <br><br>
                    <div style="margin-left:100px;"> 
                        <span><u>Date:</u> ___/___/______</span>
                        <span><u>Signature :</u> </span>
                    </div>
                    <br><br><br>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="right_ads">
            </div>


   </div> 
</page>
```

And my template, the return of my controller :

```
<?php       
    ob_start();
    try
    {
        $html2pdf = new \Html2Pdf_Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'fr');
        $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
            $html2pdf->writeHTML($html);
        $html2pdf->Output($name);
            exit;
    }
    catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
        echo $e;
        exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The render helper method returns a [Response](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html) object which is why your PDF contains HTTP headers. To get just the content of the response (your HTML) call the [getContent()](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html#method_getContent) method, e.g.

```
return $this->render('PeriscopeAdminBundle:Admin:afficher_factures_pdf.html.php', 
                        array('name'=>$name, 'html'=>$html->getContent())
                    );
```